# 2 numbers are chosen from $1,3,5..151$ and multiplied in all possible ways. Find number of ways such that product is a multiple of 5

Tags: permutations, combinations

Number of available elements = 76

Elements that are a multiple of 5 = 15

Now one perfectly acceptable answer for this is
$$\binom {30}{2} +\binom{15}{1}\times \binom {46}{1}$$

I understood how it came, that isn’t the problem.

But why can’t $\binom {15}{1} \times \binom{75}{1}$ be used? It basically means choosing 1 element from the 15 special elements and choosing 1 elements from every other number left.

Comment: Why would it not be $\binom {15}2$ in your expression?  Where does the $30$ come from?  Similarly, where do you get $46$?  Your second approach is wrong because it double counts the pairs in which both factor is a multiple of $5$.

Comment: Also:  from your calculations it appears that you are requiring that the numbers be distinct, but this is not specified in the problem.

Comment: @lulu the first solution was the given solution for this question. As for the second, how is it double counting? Both factors being multiples of 5 is a perfectly valid case

Comment: @lulu yes, I wasn’t exactly sure about it, so $\binom{75}{1}$ can be swapped with $\binom{76}{1}$

Comment: I don't understand the first solution, then.

Comment: I said you were double counting the pairs in which both terms are multiples of $5$, not that they were invalid solutions. If the pair is, say, $(5,15)$ then you count it once by specifying $5$ as the multiple of $5$ and $15$ as the "free" factor.  Then you count it again by taking $15$ as the multiple of $5$ and $5$ as the free factor.

Comment: For the first method, I would have thought the answer was $\binom {15}{2}+\binom {15}1\times \binom {61}1$.  Here, the first term reflects the ways to choose two distinct multiples of $5$ and the second reflects the ways to choose one multiple of $5$ and one non-multiple of $5$.  I think they confused themselves into thinking there were $30$ multiples of $5$, though they got the $15$ right in one place.

Comment: @lulu and in the second solution, is there any correction factor than can be added, like dividing by two to eliminate symmetric pairs

Comment: Sure, you can subtract $\binom {15}2$, as that's the number by which you over counted.

Comment: Should say:  usually, things like your second method can't be salvaged, well, not without a lot of work. That's because the pattern of multiple counting is too complex to sort out.  In this particular case it's easy to see what the over counting looks like.

Comment: @lulu is absolutely right in my view. If that is what the given solution is then I think it is wrong. Aditya, you say you understand how that answer came. Can you pls explain? I don't get it at all.

Comment: @MathLover I thought I understood it, but noticed the error when Lulu pointed it out, in which case I don’t really know what to do with it. I suspect they meant to turn the number of elements for 15 to 30 since they can be repeated, but that’s just my interpretation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

Given that we are choosing from the list $\{1,3,5,\cdots, 151\}$, that is, the odd integers from $1$ to $151$, inclusive, there are $15$ multiples of $5$ available, and $61$ non-multiples of $5$.

We wish to count the ways to choose two distinct terms from this list such that at least one of them is a multiple of $5$.  The spirit of the first calculation is: first count those pairs in which both terms are multiples of $5$ then add the pairs in which exactly one is a multiple of $5$.  The arithmetic is off, however, and the formula ought to read $$\binom {15}2+\binom {15}1\times \binom {61}1=1020$$

The second method is flawed because it double counts those pairs in which both terms are multiples of $5$.  We can fix that by subtracting the number of such pairs, namely:

$$\binom {15}1\times \binom {75}1-\binom {15}2=1020$$

As a third method, in the spirit of the proposed solution from @ChristianBlatter, we can count all possible pairs and subtract off those in which neither term is a multiple of $5$.  Thus:  $$\binom {76}2-\binom {61}2=1020$$

Comment: In case of $\binom {15}{2}$, does it account for repeated cases ie. does it count the cases when first element is 5 and second element is also 5?

Comment: No.  All three methods assume that the pair of numbers are distinct.